# Prevent svchost.exe using specific ports?

Tags: port, svchost

I know how to prevent dns.exe from using specific ports. Is it possible to do the same for svchost.exe?

EDIT: I have another application that requires the port and cannot be changed.

[image]

Comment: You can use Windows Firewall to do this.  Although you should understand by doing this, and depending on what ports you blocked and what services uses those ports, you will encounter behavior you might not expect.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I've updated the question.  In short, I have another application that uses the port so blocking with firewall wouldn't be and option in this case :-)

Comment: So which service is it? Use Sysinternals TCPView, it should have a column for that.